# Python append data with more than 1 million rows

Tags: python, pandas, hdf

I need to generate a data set with more than 1 million records and 50 columns.

I tried 2 ways to do it but i got memory error in both tries. I used ipython, 32 bit and python 2.7.

( sim.require is 10,000 records and 50 columns, i need to append 100 of them)

```
for counter in range (0,99): 
    if counter==0:
      sim_all=sim_require.copy()
   else:
      sim_all=sim_all.append(sim_require)
```

I got memory error from the above and then I saved each run to .h5 files.
So, I have 100 .h5 data sets. Each contains 10,000 records, 50 columns. Then I tried to read in all of them but still in vain.

```
os.chdir(outputs_mc)
for cnt in range(0,100):
    if cnt==0:
       sim_all= pd.DataFrame(pd.read_pickle(os.getcwd()+ '\\sim_all_'+ \
                str(cnt) +'.h5'))
    else:
        inp= pd.DataFrame(pd.read_pickle(os.getcwd()+ '\\sim_all_'+ \
                str(cnt) +'.h5'))
        sim_all=sim_all.append(inp)
```

Can someone show what is the right way to do?
Thank you.

Comment: We can't see what `sim` or `sim_require` is all about but `sim_all=sim_all.append(sim_require)` looks like a boatload of data being put into a `list`. `List`s have a lot of overhead compared to other datatypes; (e.g. dicitonaries). You should probably aim for a solution that works with individual objects/lines/pieces of information rather than everything at once. Also, are you using `numpy` or just pandas? (they're often used together). `Numpy` arrays are made for big data stuff.

Comment: Does your hardware support 64 bit python? How much memory do you have?

Comment: If Python fails with a memory error, you should wonder whether you really need to load everything in memory... It is seldom necessary.

Comment: @phebewu, what step / "piece of code" produces memory error? IMO it doesn't make much sense to pickle chunks of your data frame and then try to read them up into list of  data frames - it will consume even more memory because of additional temporary variables. What is the total size of your 100 '.h5' files?

Comment: Don't use `sim_all=sim_all.append(stuff)`. `append()` modifies the list in place and returns None.

Comment: Firstly why are you using 32-bit? Secondly read the files into a list and then `concat` to your df, what you're doing is incrementally growing your df which will cause repeated copying and allocations of memory on each iteration, rather than just doing it once at the end

Comment: You may try `sim_all = pd.concat([sim_require for i in range(99)], ignore_index=True)`, if `sim_require` is a `pd.DataFrame` object

Comment: I am using 32 bit python and my laptop has 8g ram. I cannot use 64bit python.  I made my sim_require data frame object and changed the code as follows. But the memory error shows up again when the document accumulated to 450,000 rows.          if counter==0:
           sim_all=sim_require
        else:
           sim_all = pd.concat([sim_require,sim_all], ignore_index=True)